# ember-data way for loading hasMany on demand

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have posts model where i need to load batch of replies on demand, and be able to load more. How can i do something like this? Is there a way to use ember-data `store.find` based on the parent model to have a resource like `/posts/:post_id/replies?page=1`

Any ideas if this is possible in ember-data?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass options to `store.find` that will be passed on to your server.  You could do something like this:

```
store.find('reply',{ post_id : post.get('id'), page : 1 })
```

Assuming the `post` variable has an `id` of `1`, that  would result in a call to:

```
/replies?post_id=1&page=1
```

Comment: Yes, but i have alot of other cases like this, and i can't change all these resources to match this style, and changing them all will just mess things up and create lots of duplicate resources, because API is already used by a mobile app. Any other ideas?

Comment: Currently Ember Data does not support nested API URLs.  As far as I know you options are to either structure your `find` calls as I mentioned above, roll your own adapter for Ember Data, or use something other than Ember Data all together.